# ¿Cómo saber si una función de cadena aleatoria personalizada devuelve una cadena que coincide con una expresión regular particular en Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, regex, random

### Contexto:

Una de las excelentes características que tiene la `API de Binance` es permitir a sus usuarios establecer una identificación de orden personalizada (*también conocida como* `newClientOrderId`) para cada operación que realicen en el mercado de `Binance Futures`, esta característica se vuelve útil si alguien quiere realizar un seguimiento de las transacciones que se realizaron siguiendo una estrategia de negociación en particular.

De acuerdo con sus [`Documentos oficiales`](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade), el parámetro que se enviará en la solicitud POST para poner la nueva ordeno debe ser `newClientOrderId` y su valor debe coincidir con este criterio de expresión regular: `^[\.A-Z\: /a-z0-9_-]{1,36}$`

### Problema:

Escribí una función de cadena aleatoria simple en Python que devuelve una cadena aleatoria basada en 2 parámetros que son una cadena y la longitud de la cadena deseada para combinar, aquí está:

```
import random, string
def randstr(s, length):

    all_chars = string.ascii_lowercase
    result = s
    for i in range(length):
        result += random.choice(all_chars)
    return(result)
```

##### Pruebas

```
randstr('test1',5)
Out[14]: 'test1uljgp'

randstr('test1',2)
Out[15]: 'test1mo'

randstr('test1',5)
Out[16]: 'test1pbgjw'
```

Entonces, ¿Cómo puedo saber si la salida de mi función `randstr` personalizada coincide con este criterio de expresiones regulares: `^[\.A-Z\:/a-z0-9_-]{1,36}$`? Al saber esto, me aseguraré de que los futuros desarrollos relacionados con esta API sigan funcionando sin parar.

Comment: Utiliza el modulo re de la libreria estandar. Este te permite trabajar con expresiones regulares.

Comment: https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex / https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.from_regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre puedes aplicar el método `search()` para comprobar si un string en particular satisface una expresión regular. Esto se aplica luego de llamar a la función `randstr()`

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"^[\.A-Z\: /a-z0-9_-]{1,36}$")

if patron.search(orderId):
    print(f"Order {orderId} cumple")
else:
    print(f"Order {orderId} no cumple")
```

Como el patrón ya incluye el match del principio y final de texto, usamos un `search()` en lugar de `match()`.

#### Demo

```
import random, string, re

patron = re.compile(r"^[\.A-Z\: /a-z0-9_-]{1,36}$")

def randstr(s, length):

    all_chars = string.ascii_lowercase
    result = s
    for i in range(length):
        result += random.choice(all_chars)
    return(result)

tests = [
    "AA",
    "A_A",
    "123A",
    "Aa",
    "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
]

for test in tests:
    orderId = randstr(test, 8)
    if patron.search(orderId):
        print(f"Order {orderId} cumple")
    else:
        print(f"Order {orderId} no cumple")
```

produce:

```
Order AAqiukdgcu cumple
Order A_Adymvkwty cumple
Order 123Avalwtpox cumple
Order Aaljnsyiil cumple
Order AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAinyaekji no cumple

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias tío Moe!